# Why buttons don't work when embedded in a SwiftUI Form?

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a SwitUI form. I need to draw some custom sliders. For that, I made a view (SliderView) that I include in the form several times. It took me some time to manage the Binding to get in the parent view the value of the Sliders, but I was able to do it :-)
The big mystery I'm not able to understand is why the buttons I placed in the child view, don't work when they are embedded in a Form. They work fine in a VStack. Here the code:

```
//  SliderView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct SliderView: View {
    var name: String
    var min: Double
    var max: Double
    var step: Double
    var defaultValue: Double

    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        return formatter
    }()


    @Binding var selectedValue: Double
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("\(name)")
            Slider(value: $selectedValue, in: self.min...self.max, step: self.step)
            Button(action: {
                if (self.selectedValue - self.step) >= self.min{
                    self.selectedValue = self.selectedValue - self.step
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName:"minus.circle")
            }
            Text("\(numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: selectedValue)) ?? "")")
                .padding(5)
                .onAppear {
                    self.selectedValue = self.defaultValue
                }
            Button(action: {
                if (self.selectedValue + self.step) <= self.max{
                    self.selectedValue = self.selectedValue + self.step
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName:"plus.circle")
            }


        }

    }
}

struct SliderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var myValue: Double = 1
    static var previews: some View {
        SliderView(name: "CPU", min: 1, max: 10, step: 0.5, defaultValue: 1, selectedValue: $myValue)
    }
}
```

Now, part of the form that I'm building. The code compiles, the sliders work and the value of each of them can be seen in the parent view. However, the buttons to update the sliders step by step don't work (because they are embedded in the Form)

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedCPU: Double = 1
    @State var selectedRAM: Double = 1
    @State var selectedDisk: Double = 50
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section{
                    SliderView(name: "CPU", min: 1, max: 16, step: 1, defaultValue: selectedCPU, selectedValue: $selectedCPU)
                    SliderView(name: "RAM", min: 0.5, max: 128, step: 0.5, defaultValue: selectedRAM, selectedValue: $selectedRAM)
                    SliderView(name: "SSD", min: 20, max: 500, step: 10, defaultValue: selectedDisk, selectedValue: $selectedDisk)
                }
                Section{
                    Text("CPU: \(selectedCPU)")
                    Text("RAM: \(selectedRAM)")
                    Text("SSD: \(selectedDisk)")
                }
            }
        }


    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Just replacing the "Form" with a "VStack" in the upper code, the buttons just work fine. Anyone can shed some light? I think is something regarding the different layers in the Form. When I try to click on the buttons the whole row with the slider seems to be clicked, but nothing happens.
I'm using Xcode 11 GM in MacOS 10.15 beta (19A558d)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It happens the same in Xcode 11.1 with MacOS 10.15

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From what I've been able to tell, Form rows behave differently when they contain a View that accepts a tap gesture, such as a button.  When the row contains a Button, then when the user taps on that button, everything else in the same row also receives a tap gesture.  So in your example above, it's not that your buttons are not working, what is actually happening is that they are both receiving a tap gesture and executing their action, but because of the logic in your code effectively cancels the effect of the other, it appears as if they are not working.

To help demonstrate this point, here is some test code I wrote:

```
    @State var count1 = 0
    @State var count2 = 0

    func buttonTest() -> some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.count1 += 1
            }) {
                Text("Button 1: \(count1)")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.count2 += 1
            }) {
                Text("Button 2: \(count2)")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            buttonTest()
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Test")) {
                    buttonTest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you tap either button above the form, they work independently as expected, incrementing only their own count, but if you tap either button in the Form, or anywhere else in the row, then both buttons' actions execute and both counts increment.

I'm not sure why Apple do this, but I too am struggling to find a solution to this problem.

**EDIT**

Thanks to [Shauket Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517085/4758488), there is a solution, but it makes code re-use less elegant.

So when the Button is in a Form, you need to put the code into an `.onTapGesture` handler, but if the Button is outside a Form, you need the code in the `action:` handler.

I really hope this isn't Apple's long-term position on Forms: it's goes against the write once, use everywhere philosophy.

Comment: Thank you both!! It works fine and I agree it is a bit strange. I hope Apple allows both solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check. This is still an issue as of date of 4/2020.

Comment: This is still an issue as on 6/2021, couple of days before WWDC 2021. To use onTapGesture, I replaced Button by Image itself.

Comment: "I really hope this isn't Apple's long-term position on Forms: it's goes against the write once, use everywhere philosophy"

to be fair, that philosophy doesn't hold up at all, given all the differences between iOS, iPadOS, MacOS, and WatchOS. At the end of the day, the developer is portable, but not so much of the code is (at the UI level).

Comment: Sort of, but this issue arises within a single platform. Even if the only platform you used was iOS, you’d still need to abstract the logic away from the button and have a version that called from “action:”, and another from “onTapGesture:”, then use the correct version depending on whether the button is placed in a form or outside. 

It’s still the programmer’s responsibility, but it could be more elegant.

Answer (score 25):

Try adding a buttonStyle modifier to the buttons in your Form. This worked for me:

```
Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Test")})
    ­­­­­.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: This also worked for me, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. Not sure why this behaviour is a thing!

Comment: It seems to work properly in SwiftUI now (September 2020). Just tried with and without `PlainButtonStyle()` and both worked. In fact I wouldn't use `PlainButtonStyle()` cause it removes button's foreground color

Comment: Works for me as well (December 2020) - but it does still not work (for me) without this line of code. And: I'm still able to use a foreground color for my image based button.

Comment: Worked for me also - just add the following to the button closure in order to get the foreground color back...                             .buttonStyle(.plain).foregroundColor(.green)