# Two Buttons inside HStack taking action of each other

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have created a simple List with a horizontal stack view (label, button, button). each button has his own button action but when I run I can see tap on one button print two actions. breakpoint also comes inside both actions. her is my code [image: gif]

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(self.heroViewModel.heros, id: \.self) { hero in
                Section(header: Text(hero.name)) {
                    ForEach(hero.movies, id: \.self) { movieName in
                        HStack {
                            Text(movieName)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    return
                            }.frame(width: 150, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                            Spacer()

                            Button(action: {
                                print("Rate us")
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Rate us")
                                    .background(Color.red)
                                }).padding()

                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                print("watch me")
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Watch")
                                    .background(Color.red)
                                }).padding()
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Heros List")
    }
}
```

Comment: I really hope this is just a bug (and not some crazy feature), but I hit it too, and the listed solution worked.

Comment: As of iOS 14, SwiftUI 2, this behavior still exists. Furthermore, I am unsure why tapping a button in HStack would make whole HStack to change its background color.

Comment: Still having this issue in Nov 2023!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Need to use `onTapGesture` instead of `action` like this way.

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("watch")
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(Color.red)
.onTapGesture {
    print("watch")
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but your solution is not working for me 

Comment: What issue are you facing? can you share your code with me? @Werb

Comment: This works, but really frustrating. I had to use this to have two buttons inside a Form row.

Answer (score 4):

Use Button Style

`.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())`

Example:-

```
Button(action: {
     print("Rate us")
     }, label: {
     Text("Rate us")
     .background(Color.red)
}).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this style:

.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())