# Button within stack within form is active outside of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I had some weird behavior in SwiftUI that I did not understand, and I simplified it to this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var name: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      VStack {
        Text("Line 1")
        Text("Line 2")
        Text("Line 3")
        Text("Line 4")
        Button(action: {
            print("hello world")
        }) { Text("Print hello world")}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This makes the "Line 1" ... "Line 4" texts be part of the "Print hello world" button.

If I remove the VStack in the Form they are not.

I am not sure if this is a bug in SwiftUI or if I am not understanding something that maybe I should try to understand, so: does anybody understand why Line 1 ... Line 4 would be part of the button here?

Comment: What they wanted to make, is that when you put a button inside a form, that you can activate that button by tapping anywhere in the row with the button. But of course in your case, that is not desirable! I don’t know a workaround yet...

Comment: @cbjeukendrup an workaround for that is to use `.onTapGesture { // you action } and ignore the action from button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, `Form` is a `List` under the hood, so when you create a `VStack` in it you create a row in the list, but if you remove the `VStack` there are 5 rows (4 Texts and one Button)

Comment: So does that necessarily mean that the one list item should become the complete button? What if I want to have a list item with on the bottom a button in it?

Comment: The row does not become the entire button, but when you click the row all the buttons from it are triggered, this seems like a normal behavior, you should not place more than one button in one row by design. Anyway, there is a workaround, you can use `.onTapGesture {}` on `Button`, this action will only be triggered when the button is tapped

Comment: Experimenting a bit more, I think you're right. I can add a tap gesture to line 1, an action to the button, AND a tap gesture to the button, and it looks like SwiftUI will try to find the most appropriate action to perform. Makes sense I guess.

Comment: Nice related answer in my "Related" section here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634704/15745